# Can we generate HTML report in Jenkins dashboard without redirecting to HTML page?

Tags: html, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to customize my Jenkins report view with HTML report. I can publish HTML report using HTML Publisher plugin, but this is navigating to HTML page in full window. Instead of that, I want to generate the HTML report view inside the Jenkins dashboard where testing results or graph is displayed.

Can anyone suggest how to publish my HTML page inside Jenkins dashboard, like testing results and test trend graph which are embedded on Jenkins page? If any plugins available or else any modifications in configuration of Jenkins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) but there is also a useful plugin called [DocLinks](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/DocLinks+Plugin) which allows you to publish your documents that are created in the build steps as links on the project page. Other ones are [Doxygen](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Doxygen+Plugin) and [Cucumber](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cucumber+Reports+Plugin).

Comment: visit http://jenkins-plugin-hub.herokuapp.com/?category=report for an extensive list of jenkins plugins

Comment: Hi Rachel,i am already using that HTML publisher plugin, but what i need is to display that HTML page with in jenkins UI, (JENKINS DASHBOARD), Like TestNG results, and Trend Graph, which will appear in BUILD summary, Like that I want my HTML to be displayed in Build Summary
Please suggest me with your Ideas

Comment: then use DocLinks instead i would suggest

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed Dashboard view plugin,then:

```
1.Go to Edit view
2.Select "Iframe portlate" and add path of your html file.
3.Click apply.
```

See your dashboard.It shows HTML reports there

Comment: I am not able to see "Iframe portlate" under Edit view

Comment: Have you installed Dashboard View plugin and added all your jobs under Dashboard view?

Comment: Your suggestion was very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use The [Rich Text Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Rich+Text+Publisher+Plugin) which supports Atlassian Confluence, WikiText and HTML

[image]